CORS Issue with Custom Domain on AWS Amplify - 403 Forbidden on API Request
I'm experiencing a CORS-related issue when making API requests from my custom domain hosted on AWS Amplify. The same API works fine with my Amplify-generated URL (https://your-app-name.amplifyapp.com), Vercel deployment, and other environments, but it fails with the custom domain, resulting in a 403 Forbidden response during preflight requests.
When making a POST request to the API, a preflight OPTIONS request is sent first. This request returns a 403 Forbidden status when originating from my custom domain, indicating that the request is being blocked due to CORS policy issues.
Setup

Custom Domain: https://custom.domain.com

API Endpoint: https://api.endpoint.com

Request Method: POST (with a preflight OPTIONS request)

CORS Headers from API Response:
access-control-allow-origin: * access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS access-control-allow-headers: *


Error Details
When making the request, I see the following error in the browser's console:
Access to fetch at 'https://api.endpoint.com' from origin 'https://custom.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Network Request Details

Request URL: https://api.endpoint.com

Request Method: OPTIONS

Status Code: 403 Forbidden

Response Headers:
access-control-allow-headers: * access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS access-control-allow-origin: * access-control-max-age: 86400




Verified that the API works with my Amplify app URL (https://your-app-name.amplifyapp.com), Vercel deployment, and other environments(postman).

Confirmed the custom domain is properly set up in AWS Amplify.



"indicating that the request is being blocked due to CORS policy issues" - more like, the other way around - because this request got a 403 response, it is not a successful preflight request. And therefor the actual POST request is getting blocked. So you need to go and figure out what made your system give a 403 response to the OPTIONS request in the first place in this scenario.
